# python starter screenshot using thread

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

after going through some stack overflow and external guides still was stuck with an odd problem thread starts but function not executing but used same type of setup in unity c# and visual studio C# windows application but works there fine any help would be appreciated

````
import tkinter
import threading
import PIL
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
running=False
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.screenshot)
        master.title("Screenshot Taker")
        Label(master, text="Interval between screenshots").grid(row=0,sticky=W)
        self.E1=Spinbox(master, from_ = 5, to = 1000,state = "readonly")
        self.E1.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)
        Label(master, text="File prefix").grid(row=1,sticky=W)
        self.E2=Entry(master)
        self.E2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10)
        self.B1=Button(master, text="start" ,command = self.start)
        self.B1.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3)
        self.B2=Button(master, text="stop" ,command = self.stop)
        self.B2.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3) 
    def screenshot(self):
        while(running):
            im=ImageGrab.grab()
            dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
            name=str(self.E2.get())+str(dt_string)
            logging.debug(name)
            im.save(name+".png")
            time.sleep(int(self.E1.get()))
    def start(self):
        running=True
        self.thread1.start()

    def stop(self):
        running=False
        self.thread1.join()
root = Tk()
app = app(root)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: I think you should better describe what you are trying to achieve. Currently I have no idea what you expect.

Comment: @henry actually my thread  and target funtcion is not working properly

Comment: ***"thread starts"***: It didn't, because `running=True` is local to `def start()` and you didn't see the hidden **Traceback** from `while(running):`. Read about [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Answer (score 0):

To access a global variable in python, you need to use "global var_name" in each function that needs to access it:

```py
import tkinter
import threading
import PIL
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
running=False
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.thread1=threading.Thread(target=self.screenshot)
        master.title("Screenshot Taker")
        Label(master, text="Interval between screenshots").grid(row=0,sticky=W)
        self.E1=Spinbox(master, from_ = 5, to = 1000,state = "readonly")
        self.E1.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)
        Label(master, text="File prefix").grid(row=1,sticky=W)
        self.E2=Entry(master)
        self.E2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10)
        self.B1=Button(master, text="start" ,command = self.start)
        self.B1.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3)
        self.B2=Button(master, text="stop" ,command = self.stop)
        self.B2.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3) 
    def screenshot(self):
        global running
        while(running):
            im=ImageGrab.grab()
            dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
            name=str(self.E2.get())+str(dt_string)
            logging.debug(name)
            im.save(name+".png")
            time.sleep(int(self.E1.get()))
    def start(self):
        global running
        running=True
        self.thread1.start()

    def stop(self):
        global running
        running=False
        self.thread1.join()
root = Tk()
app = app(root)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```